# Compact Sets question

Tags: real-analysis

Any hints on how to show that the set $S=\{x \in V: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is compact for any finite dimensional normed space?

I did this using Bolzano Weierstrass but that only shows it for $\mathbb{R}^n$

I'm trying to show that for every sequence in S there exists a subsequence with limit in S.

Comment: use an isomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Any choice of a basis gives rise to one). Oh, and the vector space should be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ of course, and not finite but finite dimensional.

Comment: Are you asking about $\mathbb{C}$ vs. $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Just for any finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: By "finite normed space", do you mean finite-dimensional normed space?

Comment: Yes sorry for confusion

Comment: You need completeness. The space $\mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,1]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual metric is not compact.

Comment: Please avoid making more copies of the same question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700352/quick-compactness-question

Answer (score 0):

Heine-Borel Theorem from real analysis shows that any closed bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ is compact, the latter being a consequence of the former by $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$. Now it remains to do the easy check that any vector space isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and your $n$-dimensional normed space is actually a homeomorphism.

Edit: More details:

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to V$ be a linear isomorphism. Use $f$ to transfer the inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $V$. That is, define
$$\forall v, w\in V, \quad \langle v, w\rangle:= \langle f^{-1}(v), f^{-1}(w)\rangle.$$
This inner product induces a norm on $V$, perhaps different from the norm that you started with. With this norm, it is obvious that $f$ is a homeomorphism between the two spaces. (What does $f$ and $f^{-1}$ do to balls of radius $r$?)
Now recall the elementary and standard fact that any two norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent. If you have never seen a proof of this try to show that any norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equivalent to the $\|\cdot\|_{\text{max}}$, that is, they induce the same topology, or equivalently they induce the same open sets on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it depend on the metric in $V$?

Comment: @alex The metric on $V$ is given by its norm. And any two norms on a finite dimensional normed space are equivalent in the sense that there exist positive numbers $M$ and $N$ such that $$M\|x\|\le \|x\|'\le N\|x\|$$ for any two norms $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|'$.

Comment: For any field also? The text does not specify $\mathbb R$, though I agree it might be understood.

Comment: @alex Yes. Normed vector spaces, by the definition, are over complex or real numbers. Recall the ``homogeneity'' property of the norm, $\|cv\|=|c|\|v\|.$ Here $|c|$ is the absolute value (modulus) of the scalar $c$ from the base field.

Comment: Can't it be $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @alex It depends on what you mean by "Can't it be $\mathbb{Q}?$ The usual definition of "norm" makes sense for vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$, but we usually mean complex or real spaces whenever we talk about a normed space, especially in analysis. The reason is that many useful facts, including the aforementioned equivalence of norms for a finite dimensional space require "completeness" of the field.

Comment: Then the result doesn't hold for any field $F$ for which "normed vector space over $F$" makes sense.